# Setting ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT on Staging-server does not work

Tags: asp.net-core

I have created an (system) environment variable on our staging server, named it
"ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" and set it to value "Staging".

But when logging from the server, I see that the environment is "Production".

Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Try with this: [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT", "Staging", "Machine")

Comment: Is it Windows? Linux? Is it running in Docker? IIS? Native? More information needed.

Comment: Have you configured `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` in web.config?

Comment: Feilipe,yes... rudolf: Im running windows server 2016 on my stating, Tao: I removed A_E in web.config and then it "stopped working"

Comment: Which environment did you set the variable in? The easiest way for this to happen is to set the variable in the user environment.